# Adding a layer to an image: Easy-Thumbnails

Tags: python, django, thumbnails, python-imaging-library, easy-thumbnails

In Django, I am using Easy-Thumbnails. Before saving an image file in my model field, I want to just do some process to the image, like adding a layer or an other image on or behind it.

What do I do to achieve this?

I have already wasted 4 hours trying this.

Comment: What did you try in those 4 hours? Have you any code or examples that you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can define [custom processor](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/processors/#custom-processors) and add it to your settings.